# How method calls?

Tags: user-interface, javafx-2

At the moment i am developing GUI on JavaFX 2, and i`ve found good oracle sample: FXML-LoginDemo. In this sample 2 scenes(FXML based), 1st is AuthoriseForm, 2nd is UserData changing, Main class has the next method:

```
public boolean userLogging(String userId, String password){
    if (Authenticator.validate(userId, password)) {
        loggedUser = User.of(userId);
        gotoProfile();
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

`gotoProfile();` - changing scene..

LoginController class has the next method:

```
 public void processLogin(ActionEvent event) {
        if (application == null){
            // We are running in isolated FXML, possibly in Scene Builder.
            // NO-OP.
            errorMessage.setText("Hello " + userId.getText());
        } else {
            if (!application.userLogging(userId.getText(), password.getText())){
                errorMessage.setText("Username/Password is incorrect");
            }
        }
    }
```

`processLogin()` has no calls in the code.. So the question is: How `processLogin()` calls after pressing

```
@FXML
Button login;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to the [Login.fxml](https://bitbucket.org/shemnon/javafx-gradle/src/e1f867dad7f77628883047025d19c5060686b6cc/samples/FXML-LoginDemo/src/main/resources/demo/Login.fxml?at=master) file.

That file contains this line:

```
<Button id="button1" fx:id="login" defaultButton="true" onAction="#processLogin" prefHeight="70.0" prefWidth="400.0" text="Login" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="66.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="40.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="40.0" />
```

That line sets this attribute:

```
onAction="#processLogin"
```

That attribute says that the button click (ActionEvent) should be [handled by a method defined in the controller](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controller_method_event_handlers).